# Setting the file and Video permission... so, as to use the content only by the application

Tags: android

How can we accomplished the task to avoid copy paste and read the content that we store in sdcard or phone memory, only my application can use it. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the files private to the application in internal storage [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

You could also encrypt the data of course [Encrypt Data on sdcard](http://securitymusings.com/article/2039/encrypt-stored-data-in-android).

Comment: so, if I need to store different file format then when will be the case

Comment: and these encryption and decryption technique is slower. so, it's being mostly avoided.

Comment: @user665554 yes encryption adds time, but you don't need to encrypt the whole file to make it non-usable if thats the intention (and not complete privacy) you could encrypt the first 1024 bytes or something